# Updating references using entity framework in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I have defined the following two classes:

```
public class User
{
    public System.Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public System.Guid? ContactId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
public System.Guid ContactId { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

And below is the mapping:

```
this.HasOptional(u => u.Contact)
.WithMany()
.HasForeignKey(u => u.ContactId);
```

I have defined an edit page in MVC 3 to update user info, the page contains user's properties + user's contact properties:

```
<div class="editor-field">
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
</div>

<div class="editor-field">
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contact.PhoneNumber)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Contact.PhoneNumber)
</div>
```

And in the controller's post method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(User user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(user);
}
```

But this throws:
`A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship.`  in line: `context.Entry(user)...`.

What's the cause of this exception? and how can I update User and contact entities without conflicting each other in MVC 3?
Thank you.

Comment: public System.Guid? ContactId { get; set; } cause the problem? try to remove the nullable?

Comment: Contact should be optional. I cannot make it a mandatory field.

Comment: Do you have the `User.ContactId` and `User.Contact.ContactId` properties in hidden fields on the page and post them back? I believe that the exception says that the primary key property `User.Contact.ContactId` of `Contact` (the principal) does not have the same value as the foreign key value `User.ContactId` of `User` (the dependent). These are "*the property values that define the referential constraints*" and they "*are not consistent*".

Comment: Don't you need to attach your object to the context first?

Comment: @Slauma: You were right! please Make your comment as an answer so I can accept it as the correct answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Adam: Setting the state to `Modified` attaches automatically. @Kamyar: copied comment to answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have the `User.ContactId` and `User.Contact.ContactId` properties in hidden fields on the page and post them back? I believe that the exception says that the primary key property `User.Contact.ContactId` of `Contact` (the principal) does not have the same value as the foreign key value `User.ContactId` of `User` (the dependent). These are *"the property values that define the referential constraints"* and they *"are not consistent"*.

BTW: Setting the state to `Modified` in `context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified` only affects the scalar and complex properties of the `user` entity. If the user of your view could also have changed the `Contact` data  (a navigation property) you must set the state of this entity to `Modified` as well:

```cs
context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
context.Entry(user.Contact).State = EntityState.Modified;
```